# meaning of 'P.S'/'One-oh-nine'

Tags: meaning

> I remember how you always…used to look out for me here. When that gang
>   from *“P.S.”* *one-oh-nine* would come after me for my lunch money…

The speaker is Hispanic who lived in Bronx when he was a boy.

I googled 'P.S' and 'One-oh-nine' but I can't find any clue that helps me understand this dialogue. (It seems like 'P.S' is not 'Post script' in this dialougue. Please help me!

(My native language is not English. So please be kind to me. :-))

Comment: Public school number 109, I suspect.  The schools in New York City reputedly used such numeric designations.  https://www.schools.nyc.gov/schools/K109

Comment: Thank you so much! It helpt a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. stands for "Public School". It's the name of the school they went to.  Many public schools are numbered and not named in the US to avoid any kind of bias associated with a chosen name.

In this case, the school was named "P.S. 109".

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thank you for information!

Comment: This is typical of New York City.  I haven't seen it *anywhere else* in the US -- so even if there is some other city with this scheme, it would definitely be the exception.